# How to perform range queries efficiently in GridDB for both ascending and descending order without creating separate containers?

Tags: sql, database, griddb

Using GridDB, I have a use case where I need to perform range queries on the data stored in a container. Sometimes I need to retrieve data in ascending order of a certain column, while other times I need to retrieve data in descending order of that same column. Using the current approach of creating separate containers for each order is functional but not very efficient. Is there a more efficient way to perform these range queries in GridDB, such as by inverting the order of a container or by adjusting the search criteria?